# reading a large file and forcing download

Tags: php, csv

```
$name = 'mybigfile.csv';
    $fp = fopen(...);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
       fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    fclose($fp);



// send the correct headers
header("Content-Type: application/csv etc ....");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the file and stop the script
readfile($name);
exit;
```

this method works fine but some of the files are quite big so which makes it quite slow process ... I was thinking - maybe if I could avoid the process of creating a file first and then write data and THEN read the data and output .... .i.e. if I send headers before the while loop and echo line in the while loop (instead of writing it in a line) or something like this. Would this be more efficient process? What would you suggest me to improve this process? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write directly to the output:

```
header("Content-Type: application/csv etc ....");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    fputcsv(STDOUT, $row);
}
```

See here for reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: thx .. so am i right that creating a file in this context is an overhead?

Comment: I get this error - Message:  Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' ? ... do I need to use .. php://stdout ?? ... erm ... I think this $stdout = fopen('php://stdout','w'); ...

Comment: Hmm, weird. Possibly `STDOUT` is only defined on the command line and/or it may depend on your PHP configuration. I'm not sure. But yes, opening a stream handler using `fopen('php://output', 'w')` (or `php://stdout`) should always work.

Comment: Yes, it worked with fopen('php://output', 'w'); instead of stdout ... thx for your help... :)